# C++ Alias for list of template parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, using

I have a lot of C++ classes that use the same list of template parameters

```
template<typename T, typename Index, typename Bool, typename Data, Index n_x, Index n_u, Index n_c, Index n_w>
class A {
   ...
};

template<typename T, typename Index, typename Bool, typename Data, Index n_x, Index n_u, Index n_c, Index n_w>
class B {
   ...
};

template<typename T, typename Index, typename Bool, typename Data, Index n_x, Index n_u, Index n_c, Index n_w>
class C {
   ...
};
```

You get the idea. Then I instantiate them like

```
A<T, Index, Bool, Data, n_x, n_u, n_c, n_w> a;
B<T, Index, Bool, Data, n_x, n_u, n_c, n_w> b;
C<T, Index, Bool, Data, n_x, n_u, n_c, n_w> c;
```

Is there a way to somehow create an alias for this bundle of template parameters so that I don't have to keep re-typing the argument list?

I have something like this in mind...

```
using Params = T, Index, Bool, Data, n_x, n_u, n_c, n_w;
A<Params> a;
B<Params> b;
C<Params> c;
```

I realize that I could create a separate class which just defines types, and use that. But I am wondering if there is a way of doing this without defining a new class.

EDIT

I do not want to use macros.

I also do not want to use defaults because that would require ensuring that the defaults are uniform across a bunch of files. I realize that I could define a new header of defaults and just include that in all of the files, but that just seems like bad programming.

Comment: use default parameters

Comment: Create a macro...

Comment: I do not want to use defaults because then I would have to define the defaults in every file.

Comment: I also really don't want to use a macro here

Comment: If you need something like that, then I would argue that the desing, or the implementation of that design, being flawed.

Comment: @bremen_matt Why don't you want a macro? If it serves the purpose then that should be the end of it. There is nothing inherently _wrong_ with macros. It's incorrect usage of them that _is_ a problem.

Comment: use `auto a = createA();`

Comment: @Yola the parameters cannot be inferred. I am aware of how default template parameters work.

Comment: @bremen_matt What you want is impossible. Only way is to specialize it for a type list.

Comment: One option (not saying necessarily good) is to have an outer template class `template <typename T, ...> class Params { ... };` and then have `A`, `B`, `C` as nested classes, so you'd use it like `using MyParams = Params<T, ...>;` and then `MyParams::A a;`, etc.

Comment: Ok. That you all for your input. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing some functionality of the `using` directive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly what you asked but not so different...

But require a little work.

You can solve with a struct, `foo`, with a double layer of template management.

```
template <typename T, typename Index, typename Bool, typename Data,
          Index I1, Index I2, Index I3, Index I4>
struct foo
 { 
   template <template <typename, typename X, typename, typename, X, X, X, X>
                       class Cont>
   using type = Cont<T, Index, Bool, Data, I1, I2, I3, I4>;
 };
```

A first layer, the struct layer, with the types/values you want to fix (`T, Index, Bool, Data, n_x, n_u, n_c, n_w`, in your example).

A second layer, the `using` layer, with the variable template element (`A`, `B` and `C`, in your example.

You can also add a `using` alias `foot_t` to simplify the use

```
template <template <typename, typename X, typename, typename, X, X, X, X>
                    class Cont, typename C>
using foo_t = typename C::template type<Cont>;
```

Now you can fix types and values (the first layer) with a `using`

```
using f = foo<T, Index, Bool, Data, n_x, n_u, n_c, n_w>;
```

and declare variable activating second layer using `foo_t`

```
foo_t<A, f> a;
foo_t<B, f> b;
foo_t<C, f> c;
```

The following is a full working example

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename Index, typename Bool, typename Data,
          Index n_x, Index n_u, Index n_c, Index n_w>
class A { };

template <typename T, typename Index, typename Bool, typename Data,
          Index n_x, Index n_u, Index n_c, Index n_w>
class B { };

template <typename T, typename Index, typename Bool, typename Data,
          Index n_x, Index n_u, Index n_c, Index n_w>
class C { };

template <typename T, typename Index, typename Bool, typename Data,
          Index I1, Index I2, Index I3, Index I4>
struct foo
 { 
   template <template <typename, typename X, typename, typename, X, X, X, X>
                       class Cont>
   using type = Cont<T, Index, Bool, Data, I1, I2, I3, I4>;
 };

template <template <typename, typename X, typename, typename, X, X, X, X>
                    class Cont, typename C>
using foo_t = typename C::template type<Cont>;


int main ()
 {
   using T     = float;
   using Index = std::size_t;
   using Bool  = bool;
   using Data  = std::vector<std::string>;

   constexpr std::size_t n_x { 0U };
   constexpr std::size_t n_u { 1U };
   constexpr std::size_t n_c { 2U };
   constexpr std::size_t n_w { 3U };

   using f = foo<T, Index, Bool, Data, n_x, n_u, n_c, n_w>;

   foo_t<A, f> a;
   foo_t<B, f> b;
   foo_t<C, f> c;

   static_assert( std::is_same<decltype(a),
                     A<T, Index, Bool, Data, n_x, n_u, n_c, n_w>>{}, "!" );
   static_assert( std::is_same<decltype(b),
                     B<T, Index, Bool, Data, n_x, n_u, n_c, n_w>>{}, "!" );
   static_assert( std::is_same<decltype(c),
                     C<T, Index, Bool, Data, n_x, n_u, n_c, n_w>>{}, "!" );
 }
```

Comment: Looks good. Probably about the closest one can get to what I had in mind.

Comment: This code is overcomplicated. What you need is only a composer, which can accept a container and a type then produce a composed type. `template<class T, class Index, Index n_x, template<class, class, Index>class Container>
struct Composer { using type = Container<T, Index, n_x>; };`

`template<template<class, class, size_t>class Container>
using float_sizet_0_composer = typename Composer<float, size_t, 0LU, Container>::type;`

`static_assert( std::is_same_v<float_sizet_0_composer<A>, A<float, size_t, 0LU>> );`

Comment: @liliscent - in this way you avoid the second layer... nice... but (IMHO) is significantly different from my solution; i think you should propose it as an alternative answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the alias by a define, not perfect, but easy solution and it works.

```
#define PARAMS T, Index, Bool, Data, n_x, n_u, n_c, n_w
A<PARAMS> a;
B<PARAMS> b;
C<PARAMS> c;
```

Note: no `;` at the end of the define.

Answer (score 1):

```
template <typename T, typename Index, typename Bool, typename Data, Index n_x, Index n_u, Index n_c, Index n_w>
class A
{
 ...
};


template <template<typename, typename Index, typename, typename, Index, Index, Index, Index> typename T>
using TypeInject = T<float, std::size_t, bool, std::string, 1, 2, 3, 4>;
```

use as follow:

```
TypeInject <A> a;
TypeInject <B> b;
TypeInject <C> c;
```

> The problem now is how to reduce
> `template <typename T, typename Index, typename Bool...>`. Update me if someone gets a solution.